# import * as util from "./util" vs import {someFunction} from "./util"

Tags: typescript, import

`import * as util from "./Util"`
vs 
`import {someFunction} from "./Util"`

Which one is more preferred over the other and why?

Comment: Use `import *` if you need to import everything (or many things) that `Util` exports, otherwise `import {someFunction}` works fine

Answer (score -1):

`import * as util from "./Util"` is the equivelent of `require("./Util")` in CommonJS. ES6 imports have introduced direct object destructuring assignments on imports, allowing for treeshakable libraries. Treeshaking is the process of only importing the needed code of a module. This is especially useful for web-based projects. A good example of this is [`@angular/flex-layout`](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=@angular/flex-layout@8.0.0-beta.27). The whole library has 17.6kB, but the individual exports are much smaller.

Using this for local files is only semi useful though, as parts of a module written spesifically for a project (since they are local dependencies) that are not even used in it are rarely encountered. Still it is a good practice, since the usage of a module may change as a project evolves.